# DBT Test configuration for particular scenario

Tags: dbt, dbtype

Hello Could anyone help me how to simulate this scenario. Example I want to validate these 3 fields on my table "symbol_type", "symbol_subtype", "taker_symbol" and return unique combination/result.

I tried to use this command, however Its not working properly on my test. Not sure if this is the correct syntax to simulate my scenario. Your response is highly appreciated.

[image]

Expected Result: These 3 fields should return my unique combination using DBT commands.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to either:

1. use the `generate_surrogate_key` ([docs](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#generate_surrogate_key-source)) macro in the model, or
2. use the `dbt_utils.unique_combination_of_columns` ([docs](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#unique_combination_of_columns-source)) generic test.

For the first case, you would need to define the following in the model:

```sql
select
  {{- dbt_utils.generate_surrogate_key(['symbol_type', 'symbol_subtype', 'taker_symbol']) }} as hashed_key_,
  (...)
from your_model
```

This would create a hashed value of the three columns. You could then use a `unique` test in your YAML file.

For the second case, you would only need to add the generic test in your YAML file as follows:

```yaml
# your model's YAML file
- name: your_model_name
    description: ""
    tests:
      - dbt_utils.unique_combination_of_columns:
          combination_of_columns:
            - symbol_type
            - symbol_subtype
            - taker_symbol
```

Both these approaches will let you check whether the combination of the three columns is unique over the whole model's output.

Comment: I tried to use this "dbt_utils.unique_combination_of_columns" 

  - name: mrt_deals_day_agg
    columns:
      - name: user_id
        tests:
          - dbt_utils.unique_combination_of_columns:
                  combination_of_columns:
                  - symbol
                  - execution_server_date

But I encountered an error "Compilation Error in test dbt_utils_unique_combination_of_columns_mrt_deals_day_agg_user_id__symbol__execution_server_date (models\marts\schema.yml)
  macro 'dbt_macro__test_unique_combination_of_columns' takes no keyword argument 'column_name'"

Comment: > in macro test_unique_combination_of_columns (macros\generic_tests\unique_combination_of_columns.sql)
  > called by test dbt_utils_unique_combination_of_columns_mrt_deals_day_agg_user_id__symbol__execution_server_date (models\marts\schema.yml)

Comment: I want to try generate_surrogate_key  the 1st option you mention but I don't know where I will define this. I tried to define on dbt_project.yml and generate_schema_name.sql but I'm getting an error upon adding the syntax you provided select
  {{- dbt_utils.generate_surrogate_key(['symbol_type', 'symbol_subtype', 'taker_symbol']) }} as hashed_key_,
  (...)
from mrt_deals_day_agg


Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You need to have a look at the documentation I shared with you to understand each of the options I gave you. I believe my code examples should be self-explanatory enough, though

Comment: This is now my model

WITH cte_deals_day_agg AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
        {{ ref("int_fct_deals_day_agg") }}
)

SELECT user_id, ticker_symbol, execution_server_date, total_num_deals, total_volume_usd, 
    {{- dbt_utils.generate_surrogate_key(['symbol_type', 'symbol_subtype', 'taker_symbol']) }} as hashed_key
FROM
    cte_deals_day_agg


and my schema.yml

- dbt_utils.unique_combination_of_columns:
   combination_of_columns:
      - symbol
      - execution_server_date
      - taker_symbol


I'm getting an error "no keyword on column_name"

Comment: You only need one of the two options I gave you. If you now test the uniqueness of the `hashed_key` column, you should be good to go :)